# Setting Up Google Analytics on Cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, google-analytics

Im trying to set up google analytics but I'm using cocos 2d.

The steps on google says:

```
You would update this header to:

#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController : GAITrackedViewController
```

But how can I do this seeing as my header is:

```
@interface GameMain : CCLayer <GKAchievementViewControllerDelegate, GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate, SKProductsRequestDelegate,SKPaymentTransactionObserver, MBProgressHUDDelegate >
```

Then also it says:

```
You must also provide the view name to be used in your Google Analytics reports. A good place to put this is the view controller's initializer method, if you have one, or the viewDidAppear: method:

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  self.screenName = @"About Screen";
}
```

If anyone knows the solution please tell me.

Thanks

Comment: tip: the CCDirector class is cocos2d's UIViewController, so you may need to modify the director accordingly

Comment: Could you just tell me how to do it please? Thanks

Comment: Would be much easier for me, i'd appreciate it lots! :)

Comment: Sorry, I've never done that. But in general it should be just adding the above methods to CCDirector.m and changing the director's super class.

Comment: I find it easier to learn from the answer, I'm still a newbie at this!

Comment: I can't do it dude. I've tried, i don't know what to do lol